# applying css to adjacent element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi guys what If I have a html elements like below

```html
<div>
  <div>Name</div>
  <div><input type="text" class="check">
  <div>Age</div>
  <div><input type="number" class="check"></div>
  <div>address1</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the previous elements of the elements that have .check css property.
something like Name -> *Name with read color.

Is it possible in CSS? or Do I need to mix with JS?

Any Ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What else is your `.check` class for?  You can't use css to do what you want as-is, but some minor rearrangement of the html/classes and it would be relatively straight forward

Comment: @freedomn-m you mean adding css to the elements that I want to apply certain effects?

Comment: No, I mean add `check` class to a parent element and use css `.check input { .. }` and `.check > div:first-child { color: red }` etc as an example

Comment: @freedomn-m how about adding * to the existed text? Is it possible? if we add it to the parent ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use jQuery. It's fairly straight forward there. But to my knowledge, I don't think it's achievable within pure CSS.

Comment: `.required { display:none; }` `.check .required { display:block; }` will auto-show a child element with class "required" when "check" is added to the parent.

Comment: If you're unable to change the HTML (as implied by your comment on the flex-direction answer), then please be sure to add that to the question.  Would save a lot of time.

Comment: thanks for thecomments. Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution. Changes applied:

- `input` tags no longer inside their own `div`
- `input` tag and `div` containing label changed position. CSS can only look forward.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}

input.check+div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" class="check">
    <div>Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="number" class="check">
    <div>Age</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text">
    <div>address1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.. -> CSS can only look forward

the problem is that this is already running service.. and I can't change AS-IS .. ;<

thanks for your tip tho.. I guess I have to mix with JS then ..

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that Gerard's idea seems pretty good and I would use it if I need it, but maybe you can also try giving classes to those elements you want to apply CSS to, so you can directly select those elements. If that's not what you want, you can also try using ntn-child, like so:

```
<div class="my-class">
  <div>Name</div>
  <div><input type="text" class="check">
  <div>Age</div>
  <div><input type="number" class="check"></div>
  <div>address1</div>
  <div><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.my-class:nth-child(n) {
  color: red;
}
```

Take in count that n is the child number that you want to apply the code to, so depending on how many elements are inside your parent element, you can set n to one number or another.